# Quickblox Profile Pic issue in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, quickblox

I am developing a `chat` application using `quickblox` api for chat . I am able to send and receive messages but profile picture of sender is missing. if anyone knows Please help me that How we fetch the sender `image` with messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get profile pic using below code :

```
NSUInteger userProfilePictureID = user.blobID; // user - an instance of QBUUser class

// download user profile picture
[QBRequest downloadFileWithUID:userProfilePictureID successBlock:nil statusBlock:nil errorBlock:nil];
```

Comment: you can follow the- [link](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios#Update_your_own_profile)

Comment: because I want to get all user photos like if user 1 message me then profile pic of user 1 ,user 2 then profile pic of user 2 so on....

Comment: get all users from here [link](https://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Retrieve_all_Users_for_current_account)

Comment: When we add profile pic while creating a session or while creating a chat dialog Thanks -Ankit

Comment: your welocome :) just don't forget to tell others that the "Answer is useful" :) Happy Coding